# How to have reduced opacity on parent element while maintaining full opacity on child elements

Tags: html, css, opacity

I have a banner, which depending on the chosen theme, can have a "blurred" effect:

```
opacity: 50%;
backdrop-filter: blur(50px);
```

How can I ensure that the children of the `banner` element are not "blurred" - for example it includes elements such as logos/icons/text. I've tried adding `opacity: 100%` to the individual child elements but to no avail.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.banner {
  height: 125px;
  background-color: green;
  opacity: 50%;
  backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
}

.logo {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <p class="logo">This text should be white (without reduced opacity)</p>
</div>
```

Any thoughts/ possible workarounds appreciated!

Comment: That is not really possible.

Comment: You can't do it with the structure you have, but would pseudo elements or even a different HTML stucture help (are you able to change the HTML?) Is it just a background color and/or image that you want to blur and change the opacity of?

Comment: This should be possible by using rgba on the div.

Comment: @j08691 I can't see how blur would be possible?

Comment: @AHaworth Keep the blur, but remove the opacity rule and use it in the rgba instead. That way the child text is unaffected but the opacity on the div stays

Comment: I think this is the way to go, removing opacity and using rgba instead, thank you!